# Quickblox: Blocking Unblocking and BlockList in WEB Chat

Tags: javascript, quickblox, web-chat

I wanted to add feature of blocking, unblocking and retrieving block users listing in my chat web application.

For this, I modified quickblox.js by adding new function to get blocklist below `_enableCarbons()` function as:

```
getBlockList: function() {
        iq = $iq({
        //from: connection.jid,    //Also tried to sent this but same response was received
        type: 'get',
        id: connection.getUniqueId('sendIQ')
    }).c('blocklist', {
        xmlns: "urn:xmpp:blocking"
    });

    connection.sendIQ(iq, function(stanza) {
      console.log("response of getBlockList",stanza);
      callback();
    });
}
```

On calling above function below xml is sent to server :

```
<iq type="get" id="3:sendIQ" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <blocklist xmlns="urn:xmpp:blocking"></blocklist>
</iq>
```

which in response sends below xml:

```
<iq id="3:sendIQ" to="3056272-18345@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-228541" type="error" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <blocklist xmlns="urn:xmpp:blocking"></blocklist>
    <error type="cancel" code="501">
        <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></feature-not-implemented>
        <text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" xml:lang="en">Feature not supported yet.</text>
    </error>
</iq>
```

Kindly let me know if I need to send something else too or something wrong am I doing.
I followed http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0191.html link to retrieve block list

I also followed XEP-0016 and changed by code for adding a user to a privacy list as :

```
block : function(userId,callback) {
iq = $iq({
  from: connection.jid,
  type: 'set',
  id: connection.getUniqueId('sendIQ')
}).c('query', {
  xmlns: "jabber:iq:privacy"
}).c('list',{
  name : 'public'
}).c('item',{
  type : 'jid',
  value : this.helpers.getUserJid(userId, this.service.getSession().application_id),
  action : 'deny',
  order : new Date().getTime()
});

connection.sendIQ(iq, function(stanza) {
  console.log("response of getBlockList",stanza);
  callback(stanza);
});
}
```

This send below XML:

```
<iq from="userid-appId@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-233195" type="set" id="3:sendIQ" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy">
    <list name="public">
        <item type="jid" value="idOfUserToBlock-appId@chat.quickblox.com" action="deny" order="1444815897276"></item>
    </list>
</query>
</iq>
```

Response that I got from server is :

```
<iq id="3:sendIQ" to="chatID-appID@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-233195" type="error" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy">
    <list name="public">
        <item value="blockChatID-appID@chat.quickblox.com" action="deny" order="1444815897276" type="jid"></item>
    </list>
</query>
<error type="modify" code="400">
    <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></bad-request>
</error>
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privacy Lists API is available starting from 1.17.1 version QuickBlox Javascript SDK

Here is also the API documentation

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Privacy_lists

Answer (score 0):

QuickBlox uses XEP-0016 Privacy Lists for the blocking functionality

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html

please follow it instead of 0191

Comment: I tried that too but got error in response with bad-request. I just updated my post above, please check and let me know what's wrong in that.

Comment: The 'order' attribute MUST be included and its value MUST be a non-negative integer that is unique among all items in the list. (If a client attempts to create or update a list with non-unique order values, the server MUST return to the client a <bad-request/> stanza error.)

Comment: How would I identify that the order number is unique while sending request to add item in list.

Comment: you probably can use UserID as the order, it's always unique

Comment: @IgorKhomenko: Thanks for your reply, I am able to add a user in privacy list, but while retrieving list it always returns me user that I added last. Do I need to add all the users again that were added earlier while adding a new user within a list? Please if you can assist me providing a sample code for this then it will be a great favor. Also the user who is in my privacy list is still able to send me message. Can you explain me why and when this happens.

Comment: you can have many privacy lists. you can choose one as active and default, then it will work

Comment: @IgorKhomenko: Thanks for that information. I understand but creating more than one privacy list and making active out of one of them won't solve my purpose. As I want to add users within a single list. Kindly let me know if I can update a list with appending a new user within that list or I need to specify all the users again?

Comment: you have to retrieve it, add new user and set a new list again.

Comment: @IgorKhomenko: Ok, But in my above comment on 15 Oct, I also mentioned that I added a user in my privacy list and I tried to send message from that user, and it was delivered to me. Also, If I hit a message API to send a message to user will this also get checked by privacy list?

Comment: Yes it will. Also please check that you set the privacy list as default and active